# Center the form in the div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my form in the Div "fromArea". But nothing happen when I'm using "display:flex", "align-content: center". However, when I'm using "margin-left: 60px" on the form, I get the content in the middle.

I tried with : "display:flex", "align-content: center"

Html:

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class=formArea>

            <form>
                <h1>Contact us!</h1>
                <input type="text" id=firstName placeholder="First name"><br>
                <input type="text" id=lastName placeholder="Last name"><br>
                <input type="text" id=City placeholder="City"><br>
                <input type="email" id=email placeholder="Email"><br>
                <input type="phone" id=phone placeholder="Phone"><br>
                <textarea name="yourMessage" id="yourMessage" cols="" rows="" style="text-align:left; overflow:auto;"
                    placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id=submit><br>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Css:

```
.formArea {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 590px;
    margin: 0 30%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 193, 177, .3);
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 193, 177, .3);
    position: relative;
}

form {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

I want to center the form in the .formArea without using "margin-left: 60px;" as you can see in my Css script (form).

Comment: `align-content` is for vertical alignment, `justify-content` is for horizontal alignment. Using `justify-content: center` will likely do what you want. Check out [CSS-Tricks Flexbox Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a perfect center, horizontaly and verticaly use

```
.formArea {
    width: 500px;  /* whatever width  to center in */
    height: 500px; /* whatever height to center in */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
.formArea h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.formArea form {
    width: 250px; /* or in % but smaller then formArea width */
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input#submit {
    width: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
textarea {
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.formArea {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

for your inner form you want to align in the Div.
Alternatively, you could use the

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

it's better you use F12 or Firebug(Addon) on your browser to see enter active changes

all of the answers you can test and also test the following:

`<div class=formArea>`
`<center>`
`your form's code` 
`<center>`
`</div>`